# Java - prefix a character before each word in string

Tags: java, regex, string

I am looking for a function that prefixes a character before each identified word in a given string. Eg: when I pass a string "`(var1 + var2-var3 + 30)%var4`", I must expect "`($var1 + $var2-$var3 + 30)%$var4`". In the given string, only the words must be identified and '`$`' must be prefixed. All numbers, white spaces, operators (+, -, *, /, %) must be ignored.

Comment: Your teacher probably gave you some hints how to do this.  What code have you tried?  Please show us the code you made so far.

Comment: I suggest that you take a look at regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OOTB, there does not exist any such function. You can define a function which would use a regex e.g. `(?i)(?:[a-z_]\w+)` to identify variable words and replace them with `\$$0` where `$0` refers to the match (the replaceable parameter) and `\$` before it is for prefixing `$` to it.

**Note:** I am assuming the variable words may include an underscore (i.e. `_`). If not, use the RegEx [pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), `(?i)(?:[a-z]\p{Alnum}+)`. Note that `\w` includes alphabets, digits and underscore.

**Dem:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(getString("(var1 + var2-var3 + 30)%var4"));
    }

    static String getString(String str) {
        return str.replaceAll("(?i)(?:[a-z_]\\w+)", "\\$$0");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
($var1 + $var2-$var3 + 30)%$var4
```

**Explanation of the regex at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rO55IF/1):**

[image]